# Uploading an image to mongodb using Multer with Express and Axios

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, axios, multer

I am basically trying to make a small application which allows an admin user to enter a name, price and image of a product which can then be viewed on another page. The details will be sent to a mongo database which will be performed via an axios post from the front end. I can send the name and the price no problem which can be seen on the front end dynamically, however, I am unable to send image to the mongo database which i've been trying to achieve now for quite some time.

I am using multer and axios to try and sent the file over as the application is a react app. I think the problem is to do with the "req.file" within the back end of the application. The code below is my endpoint:

api.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var cors        = require('cors')
var app         = express();
var mongodb     = require('mongodb');
var path        = require('path');
var fsextra     = require('fs-extra');
var fs          = require('fs')
var util        = require('util')
var multer      = require('multer')
var upload      = multer( {dest:  __dirname + '/uploads'} )
var ejs         = require('ejs')

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react', 'build')));
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
console.log(__dirname)
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
var db;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<mydbdetails>', (err, database) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    process.exit(1);
  }
  db = database;
  console.log('Database connection is ready')

});
var server= app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8082, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});



app.post('/api/submitImage', upload.single('inputForm'), function(req,res){
  var file = req.body.file
    if (file == null) {
    // If Submit was accidentally clicked with no file selected...
      //res.render('admin', { title:'Please select a picture file to submit!'});
      res.send({success: false, message: "dsfdsg"})
      console.log('There is no file present')
      console.log(req.file,'file')
  }
  else{
    // read the img file from tmp in-memory location
   var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.files.path);
   console.log(newImg,'details of the new image')
   // encode the file as a base64 string.
   var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
   console.log(encImg,'kdfjndodj')
   // define your new document
   var newItem = {
      description: req.body.description,
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      size: req.files.size,
      img: Buffer(encImg, 'base64')
    };
    db.collection('products').insert(newItem, function(err, result){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      var newoid = new ObjectId(result.ops[0]._id);
      fs.remove(req.file.path, function(err) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) };
        res.render('./src/components/adminContainer.js', {title:'Thanks for the Picture!'});
      });
    })
  }
})
```

The next code is the how I am trying to send it over using Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class ProductsApi {

  static submitProduct(name,prices,callback){

      axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/submitProduct', {name: name, prices: prices})
        .then( response => {
        callback(response)
    })
  }
  static viewName(callback){
    axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/retrieveName')
      .then( response => {
        return callback(response)
    })
  }
  static viewPrice(callback){
    axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/retrievePrice')
      .then( response => {
        return callback(response)
    })
  }
  static viewProducts(callback){
    axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/retrieveProducts')
      .then( response => {
        return callback(response)
    })
  }
  static submitImages(image,callback){
    axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/submitImage',{image: image})
      .then( response => {
        return callback(response)
        console.log('response has been made,', image,'has been recieved by axios')
    })
  }
}


export default ProductsApi;
```

The last file is how I am trying to send the file to the database using react with event handlers:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
  import '../App.css'
  import AppHeader from './appHeader.js'
  import ProductsApi from '../api/axios.js'

  const AdminContainer = () => {
    return(
      <div>
      <AppHeader />
      <FormContainer />
      </div>
    )
  }

  class FormContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        file: '',
        inputName: '',
        inputPrice: '',
        image: ''
      };
      this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
      this.handlePriceChange = this.handlePriceChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.sendName = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleNameChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        name : e.target.value,
      })
    }
    handlePriceChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        prices : e.target.value
      })
    }
    sendName(e){
      this.setState({
        inputName: e.target.value,
        inputName:e.target.value
      })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();


    console.log('attempting to access axios...')
    ProductsApi.submitProduct(this.state.name, this.state.prices, resp => {
        console.log('response has been made', resp)
        //if error message, add to state and show error message on front end
        this.setState({
          inputName:this.state.name,
          inputPrice:this.state.prices
        },function(){
          console.log(resp,'this is resp')
          console.log('Axios has send ',this.state.name,' to the database')

        });
      })

      console.log(this.state.prices,'This is the new price')
      console.log(this.state.name,'This is the new name')

    ProductsApi.submitImages(this.state.image, response => {
        console.log('axios has been notified to submit an image...')
        this.setState({
          image: this.state.image
        },function(){
          console.log('Image submission axios response details are as follows: ', response)
          console.log(this.state.image, ': has been sent to the db')
        })
    })
  }

    render(){
      return(

        <div>
          <h2>Add a new product to the Shop</h2>
          <div className='formWrapper'>
            <div className='center'>
              <form name='inputForm' encType='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
                <label>
                  Name:
                  <input value = {this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} type="text" placeholder='Name' /><br />
                  Price:
                  <input value = {this.state.prices} onChange={this.handlePriceChange} type='text' /><br />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Choose an Image:
                  <input className='imgInsert' name ='inputForm' type='file'/>
                </label>
                <div>
                <img className = 'previewImage' value={this.state.image}/>
                </div>
                <button className='btn updateBtn' onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

  }


  export default AdminContainer
```

Common errors I am getting when trying debug it is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined."

and "file" being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multer to save images you need to make sure that the image comes to the server as form data. this is because multer requires the multipart/form-data encoding which you do not get when submitting a form with an ajax request unless if you specifically do something to make it happen.
You can do this by using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object. [Here](https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef) is an example of this being used. I hope this helps.